# Parse error with same name nested tags using python xml to json

Tags: python, xml, json, mongodb, gzip

I have a small set back I have a large xml file in the following format

```
<doc id="1">Some text</doc>
<doc id="2">more text</doc>
```

Im using the following python script to convert into a json format:

```
from sys import stdout

import xmltodict
import gzip
import json

count = 0
xmlSrc = 'text.xml.gz'
jsDest = 'js/cd.js'

def parseNode(_, node):
    global count
    count += 1
    stdout.write("\r%d" % count)

    jsonNode = json.dumps(node)
    f.write(jsonNode + '\n')
    return True

f = open(jsDest, 'w')

xmltodict.parse(gzip.open(xmlSrc), item_depth=2, item_callback=parseNode)

f.close()

stdout.write("\n") # move the cursor to the next line
```

Is it possible to detected the end `</doc>` and break and then continue converting? Ive looked at other stackoverflow question but none help. [How do you parse nested XML tags with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186343/how-do-you-parse-nested-xml-tags-with-python)

Comment: Are your **<doc>** tags flat and not nested?

Comment: Hi Anzel my tags are <doc id="12" url="http://example.com" title="Anarchism">
Anarchism ....
</doc>

<doc id="123" url="http://example2" title="Laptop">
Laptop ....
</doc> inside one large xml that i wish to parse or breakup in json to import into mongo

Comment: OK, do you want to extract <doc> elements or EXCLUDE them?

Comment: I want to extract <doc> and get a format that mongodb friendly {
    doc:[
        {
            id:307,
            url:'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=307',
            title:'Abraham Lincoln'
        },

Comment: http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

Comment: I have provided an answer, all you need is to serialize the json object from Python dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `<doc>` tag isn't nested itself, you can iterate the document and manually serialize the object and dump to `json`, here is an example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

s= '''
<root>
    <abc>
        <doc id="12" url="example.com" title="Anarchism"> Anarchism .... </doc>
    </abc>
    <doc id="123" url="example2" title="Laptop"> Laptop .... </doc>
    <def>
        <doc id="3">Final text</doc>
    </def>
</root>
'''

tree = ET.fromstring(s)
j = []
# use iterfind will iterate the element tree and find the doc element
for node in tree.iterfind('.//doc'):
    # manually build the dict with doc attribute and text
    attrib = {}
    attrib.update(node.attrib)
    attrib.update({'text': node.text})
    d = {'doc': [ attrib ] }
    j.append(d)

json.dumps(j)
'[{"doc": [{"url": "example.com", "text": " Anarchism .... ", "id": "12", "title": "Anarchism"}]}, {"doc": [{"url": "example2", "text": " Laptop .... ", "id": "123", "title": "Laptop"}]}, {"doc": [{"text": "Final text", "id": "3"}]}]'

# to write to a json file
with open('yourjsonfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(j))
```